# The critical point of gold -- how did they measure this?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

I was looking up something far more mundane and noticed this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)

```
Gold:
Critical point: 7250K
Critical pressure: 5,000 atm.
```

Now, it's pretty clear they don't have much precision to these values, but how did they measure them at all?  What could possibly contain something that hot and under that much pressure??

Comment: Researchers have been known to publish their methods in scientific journals. The first return for "gold critical point" on Google Scholar is Boboridis, K., Pottlacher, G. & Jäger, H. "Determination of the Critical Point of Gold." International Journal of Thermophysics 20, 1289–1297 (1999). [https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1022687811410](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022687811410). The methods are summarized in the abstract and of course elaborated upon in the body of the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@The_Sympathizer is mostly correct. This [link](https://graz.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/determination-of-the-critical-point-of-gold) will lead you to a paper published in the International Journal of Thermophysics by Konstantinos Boboridis and others. The general procedure requires small gold filaments to be resistively heated under extremely high pressures of up to 600MPa.

They follow the changes in electrical conductivity and thermal expansion of the gold filaments to monitor each phase transition.  This setup allows them to monitor changes in the material with submicrosecond resolution.